# adding image widget on gtklayout

Tags: gtk

I have put an image on gtklayout calling put method, but i could not get the image visible.
  What is the procedure for putting an image gtklayout object so that it appears as its back ground.

Regards,
iSight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pls check if the code below would work for you:

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *layout;
    GtkWidget *image;
    GtkWidget *button;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 290, 200);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);

    layout = gtk_layout_new(NULL, NULL);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (window), layout);
    gtk_widget_show(layout);

    image = gtk_image_new_from_file("/home/my_test_image.jpg"); // put path to your image here
    gtk_layout_put(GTK_LAYOUT(layout), image, 0, 0);

    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Button");
    gtk_layout_put(GTK_LAYOUT(layout), button, 150, 50);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(button, 80, 35);

    g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
    G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

hope this helps, regards